# Ubuntu 14.04 - undo mdadm raid1 lvm system, 2nd disk as emergency recover

Tags: 14.04, raid, mdadm

I have a (remote) Ubuntu 14.04 (XFCE desktop) system which is configured with RAID1 (2 identical disks):

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid1] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      1953382208 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

Inside /dev/md0 is a boot partition (partition 0: 244M), and an LVM VG/PV (partition 5) which contains two volumes: the root system (1.8T) and a swap (12G).

I want to mess with the system (upgrade to 16.04 and then make other changes) and I would prefer to keep the 2nd disk of the raid configuration as a backup so if all goes pear-shaped I can go back to that and recover the original configuration and data.

I read that I can remove the existing RAID configuration with:

```
mdadm /dev/md1 --fail /dev/sdb1 --remove /dev/sdb1
```

I'm not sure if I have to do anything to else to stop sdb1 being re-added to the array when the system reboots? For instance

```
wipefs -a /dev/sdb1
mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --raid-devices=1
```

I need to be sure that after my work is complete I can either add back /dev/sdb1 to the raid array so that it can be conformed to the (now updated) data in /dev/sda1 or, alternatively, that I can boot from /dev/sdb as the 'old' system and use it to rebuild /dev/sda (if it is in a bad state after a botched upgrade). I realise that booting from /dev/sdb may require local access, but will it be bootable at all when it used to be part of a raid1 device?

Any guidance gratefully received.

Comment: Do not have the expertise to give an exact answer but here is a scenario you could do: fail and remove `/dev/sdb1` as you mention, this is your backup drive. Update your Ubuntu on `/dev/sda`. If something goes wrong, abandon your raid array entirely and use [instructions like these](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Convert_a_single_drive_system_to_RAID) to build a brand new raid config using your `/dev/sdb1`

Comment: The idea here is that you are not "trying to tell your old RAID that it should use the `/dev/sdb` to rebuild" but rather "forget the old RAID and use `/dev/sdb` from that old RAID to build a new RAID without needing a third disk"

Comment: in the end I managed to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 without altering RAID. But I have been testing (in a similar test environment, but now with Ubuntu 16.04): I can fail and remove /dev/sdb1 but if I bring it back as a new single-drive raid device (while system is running from the old now-single-drive RAID device on /dev/sda1) a disaster unfolds because LVM automatically and (it seems) inescapably recognises the PV on /dev/sdb1 as being the same as the one on /dev/sda1 (although they are now in different RAID arrays) and locks down any attempt to work with it independently.